# ROS Answers SE migration: Ptam problem

Tags: ros, ethzasl-ptam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi Dear ros experts.

I have problem ethzasl_ptam.

I installted rqt but I received this message.

how to fix it?

ethzasl_ptam/rqt_ptam/src/rqt_ptam/remote_ptam.cpp:326:65: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion at end of input

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/139586/ptam-problem/) by [sungmok](https://answers.ros.org/users/13281/sungmok/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Answer copied from the github issue

find it here: https://github.com/ethz-asl/ethzasl_ptam/issues/28

rqt_ptam was written with support for groovy and later only. One difference is the pluginlib macro which fails compiling in your code. In fuerte, it used to have 4 arguments. Here is a description what you need to change:
http://wiki.ros.org/pluginlib (and switch to fuerte) also, when you switch to the groovy documentation, there is a migration guide at 5) for fuerte --> groovy, which you essentially would have to revert. However, if possible, I'd consider upgrading to hydro since fuerte is deprecated with the release of hydro.

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2014-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0